# How to add --whole-archive flag to a imported target in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm using a library that provides some imported libraries for linking into your code. Here is a example of these imported libraries:

```
add_library(ABC STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(ABC PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "XYZ"
)
```

which I use it easily in `target_link_libraries()`. The problem is that I need to link this specific library with `--whole-archive` (and in dynamic case with `--no-as-needed`) option. What is best way to do so? One way to do is to use `target_link_options()` I guess, and use use library directly rather than this imported target. But I wonder if there is any better way or not.

Comment: Did you try setting this using the [`STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS.html#prop_tgt:STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS) property?

Comment: @squareskittles yea,did not work.